# File custom.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property

Tags: c#, .net, angular, angular5

I'm writing CURD Angular 5 with .Net API Custom . Now I'm have a error with class Model custom in Angular 5
This is message error
Failed to compile.

```
./src/app/model/customer.model.ts
Module build failed: Error: 
D:\Angular\Project\CustomerApp\CustomerApp\ClientApp\src\app\model\customer.model.ts is missing from 
the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' 
property.
at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile
```

This is my file tsconfig.app.json

```
{

"extends": "../tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {
"outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
"baseUrl": "./",
"module": "es2015",
"types": []
},
"exclude": [
"test.ts",
"**/*.spec.ts"
]
}
```

I tried to edit file tsConfig.app.json with add src/**/*.ts in "exclude":

```
{
"extends": "../tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {
"outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
"baseUrl": "./",
"module": "es2015",
"types": []`enter code here`
},
"exclude": [
"test.ts",
"**/*.spec.ts",
"src/**/*.ts"
]
}
```

But don't work . Help me please !!!

Comment: how import the file in the component or service you need it?, must be `import {Model} from './app/model/customer.model'` -well relative to the component, can be  e.g. `import {Model} from '../model/customer.model'` if the component or service is in a folder app/component

Comment: Thanks for read my question :)
Now I'm import model as below : import { Customer } from '../../model/customer.model';
My file name model is Customer.model.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first , my name file model is customer.model.ts
and import in component as below :

```
import { Customer } from '../../model/customer.model';
```

Then I change name of file model to customer.ts
and import in component change to :

```
import { Customer } from '../../model/customer';
```

Now it's working good .